# Uploading zip archives using for each loop in php causes repetition of zip archives in zip file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In PHP CodeIgniter I am trying to get and extract multiple zip files from remote source as:

```
foreach($it as $a) {
    $file='http://www.yifysubtitles.com/subtitle/'.strip_tags($a).'.zip';
    $newfile = strip_tags($a).'.zip';

    if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
        echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
    } else {
        $open = zip_open($newfile);
        if (is_numeric($open)) {
            echo "Zip Open Error #: $open";
        } else {    
            while($zip = zip_read($open)) {
                zip_entry_open($zip);
                $text = zip_entry_read($zip , zip_entry_filesize($zip));
                zip_entry_close($zip);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $name = strip_tags($a[0]).".srt";
    $this->zip->add_data($name, $text);
    $this->zip->archive('assets/subtitles/'.strip_tags($a).'.zip');
}
```

The first time the zip file is uploaded to the server it works fine, but when the loop executes a second time the zip file contain two zip archives, second zip file contains the first archive also.
i,e

1

12

123

but I want as

1

2

3

Where I am wrong?
when data added for second time previous archives are also added to zip. how to avoid this.
for each iteration only current file data should be uploaded to server.

Comment: i want to clear previous iteration for each loop data. and only current file data should be added to zip file

Comment: previous archive zip entries should not added to current archive

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular library. Does `$this->zip` need to be re-initialized each time through the loop? Maybe it's retaining all the earlier information and adding to it instead of starting over with each file?

Comment: yes $this->zip is built in codeigniter library. which may hold cache data.

Comment: So, you need to initialize it every time through the loop to clear that cache? Or no?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
$this->load->library('zip');
$zip = $this->zip->CI_Zip();
$zip->add_data($name, $text);
$zip->archive('assets/subtitles/'.strip_tags($a).'.zip');
```

Comment: @GulzarAli :- Please add your static array in question code ($it).

Answer (score 0):

After lots of tries I have found that it was due to codeigniter zip archive library use cache data and next time more data add to it. so this was the solution

```
                    $this->load->library('zip');
                    $name = strip_tags($a).".srt";
                    $this->zip->add_data($name, $text);
                    $this->zip->archive('assets/subtitles/'.strip_tags($a).'.zip');
```

I just have to add this line of simple code

```
                     $this->zip->clear_data();
```

which prevent archive to hold previous data.

Comment: So, it's exactly what I suggested it might be? Seems that might warrant at least an upvote on my comment... :-)